# How to make a simple jump animation using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web, animation

I am trying to make a character jump using jQuery. I am not very good in JavaScript so please excuse my code if it isn't up to standards. Also worth mentionning the function gets called earlier in the code and there is an eventListener for keyup/keydown events earlier as well. Also if it can help, I am getting an error saying animate() is not a function in my browser  inspector but I know the jQuery library is correctly included

I tried this:

```
sauter: function () {
        if (!personnage.enSaut) {
            let lePersonnage = document.getElementById("personnage");
            $("#personnage").animate({ top: "-=100px" }, 1000)
                .animate({ top: "+=100px" }, 1000)
                .promise()
                .done(personnage.resetSaut);
            clearInterval(personnage.threadMarcherCourir);
            // lePersonnage.classList.add("sauter");
            personnage.enSaut = true;
        }
    },

    /*
        Méthode qui permet de réinitialiser l'objet et le personnage à la fin du saut.
        Cette méthode sera appelée lors de l'événement "animationend" à la fin d'un saut ou lors du    début d'une nouvelle
        partie.
     */
    resetSaut: function () {
        let timeoutMouvement = 60;

        personnage.enSaut = false;

        if (personnage.directionSouhaitee !== personnage.ARRET) {
            if (clavier.touchesAppuyees.includes(clavier.MAJUSCULE)) {
                timeoutMouvement /= 2;
            }
            if (partieEnCours) {
                clearInterval(personnage.threadMarcherCourir);
                personnage.threadMarcherCourir = setInterval(personnage.marcher, timeoutMouvement);
            }
        }
    }`
```

but nothing is happening but I know that my sauter function is being called since the clearInterval in it works. This is what I get using console.log($.fn.jquery):
3.5.1 -ajax,-ajax/jsonp,-ajax/load,-ajax/script,-ajax/var/location,-ajax/var/nonce,-ajax/var/rquery,-ajax/xhr,-manipulation/_evalUrl,-deprecated/ajax-event-alias,-effects,-effects/Tween,-effects/animatedSelector

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Code existant...

  // Ajoute l'événement click à un bouton ou à un élément pour déclencher le saut.
  $("#boutondesaut").click(function() {
    if (!personnage.enSaut) {
      let lePersonnage = $("#personnage");
      lePersonnage.animate({
          top: "-=100px"
        }, 1000)
        .animate({
          top: "+=100px"
        }, 1000)
        .promise()
        .done(personnage.resetSaut);
      clearInterval(personnage.threadMarcherCourir);
      personnage.enSaut = true;
    }
  });

  // Fonction pour réinitialiser le saut à la fin de l'animation
  personnage.resetSaut = function() {
    let timeoutMouvement = 60;

    personnage.enSaut = false;

    if (personnage.directionSouhaitee !== personnage.ARRET) {
      if (clavier.touchesAppuyees.includes(clavier.MAJUSCULE)) {
        timeoutMouvement /= 2;
      }
      if (partieEnCours) {
        clearInterval(personnage.threadMarcherCourir);
        personnage.threadMarcherCourir = setInterval(personnage.marcher, timeoutMouvement);
      }
    }
  };

  // Code existant...
});
```

Comment: This is where my fucntion gets called: if (hautAppuyee) {
                clearInterval(personnage.threadMarcherCourir);
                personnage.sauter(); I'll also edit my post. And I have an eventListener for the keyup/keydown events

Comment: Code-only answers are more difficult for future viewers to understand. You should explain how you solved the problem along with any code you want to share.